# My flair not shown after wearing the hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

My flair not shown after I wear the hat

This is the hat on the profile picture:
[image]

And this is my flair now on a post:
[image]

Just like that!
Can anyone help, or it is a bug?

Comment: Where are you trying to view the flair? I can see it just fine on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/154542/ahmed-hamdy/flair

Comment: But I just opened the link and found all my flair styles without the hat?

Comment: You expected the hat on your flair? Is that the bug?

Comment: I don't say bug, I just wonder where is the hat on the flair?

Comment: You originally tagged this with [meta-tag:bug]. If you wanted support, you should have used that tag...

Comment: You are right, I am sorry for this mistake. Thanks for your edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your issue

I've looked at your posts and I think you mean this one :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20633794/1063093

The post is now a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). So no, your usercard won't show at all. Only your username. This is by design

### Now

The flair appears fine even with the hats.

> [image]
>
> [image]

The hats won't appear on your flair though and that is by design.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts :)
But now you mean the default behavior is that the hat won't appear on the flair, right?

Comment: @AhmedHamdy yes