# Why doesn't my flair wear any of the Winter Bash caps which I wear and remains uncapped?

Tags: discussion, flair, winter-bash

Why doesn't my flair wears any of the Winter Bash caps which I wear and remains uncapped throughout?

[image: flair]

Update: As pointed out this question about being a duplicate of [flair not shown after wearing the hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212100/my-flair-not-shown-after-wearing-the-hat) is a different question all together, where as this question is about *why my flair doesn't wears the Winter Bash caps*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My flair not shown after wearing the hat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212100/my-flair-not-shown-after-wearing-the-hat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flair is a network-wide feature. Just like you see no hats/snowflake in the top bar on https://stackexchange.com, and your [profile description](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) has to be maintained separately, your flair won't display a hat. This is lot easier to develop than to choose which of the 173 sites it should mirror.